# MYSQL me devuelve fechas erroneas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema, he estado tratando de seleccionar un rango de fechas especifico (Mayo) pero cuando hago la consulta estoy viendo que me devuelve resultados que no estan en el rango que estoy solicitando:

El query que hago:

SELECT * FROM (nombre_tabla) WHERE fecha_expiracion between '01-05-2019' AND '31-05-2019'

Pero...me esta devolviendo muchos datos y ademas fuera del rango de fechas como se muestra en la imagen:

El formato es dd/mm/yyyy

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Los campos que tiene esta tabla son estos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto tambien alguna informacion que ya esta en la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias poner el formato en el que estan las fechas en esa tabla?

Comment: Claro, si lo mencione por ahi me parece, esta como dia-mes-año por eso no entiendo por que me devuelve fechas que no tienen sentido, si te das cuenta hay una fecha que dice, 21-01-2019 (21 enero 2019), para no poner una imagen tan grande corte varias otras pero tambien me salen hasta de 2018 y 2020 en fecha de expiracion

Comment: no. como definiste el campo al crear la base de datos. Cual es el formato del campo

Comment: Como fue creado, cual es el formato de ese campo? cual es el formato general en que se guardan fechas (si es un campo fecha) en esa base de datos?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lee estos links por favor

Comment: Disculpa yo no cree la base de datos, como veo eso? Aun soy algo nuevo en mysql

Comment: `DESCRIBE tutabla;` has este comando y saldrá el tipo de dato

Comment: Ok segun DESCRIBE (mi_tabla) fecha_expiracion es un varchar(45).

Comment: Entonces tu fecha no es un campo date.. con lo cual tu query no va a andar nunca como vos esperas... VAmos a necesitar ver los datos de tu tabla.. no ves lo que vos esperas, porque al ser un campo de texto, el between hace cosas muy raras

Comment: Se puede cambiar la forma de guardar los datos en esa tabla?esa forma de guardar fechas es muy pero muy problematica. Si queres guardarlas como texto, deben estar en formato YYYYMMDD

Comment: No...segun me dijeron no puedo hacer cambios a la base de datos, pero tal vez un cambio de tipo si se pueda, mañana consultaria eso, pero si hay una de hacerlo sin modificar la BD lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Los datos de fecha se deben guardar como YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS. En la consulta, o en el lenguaje de programación que vas a usar, haces las conversiones para los usuarios. Es un estándar y evita muchos dolores de cabeza. Incluso aunque la columna sea VARCHAR una consulta simple te va a traer los valores correctos.

Comment: Podrias darme alguna referencia de como hacer eso? Por que ya hay muchos datos en la BD y se guardan ya como varchar ese par de fechas, así que me gustaria saber es como puedo hacer en este caso, me dijeron que filtre de una fecha a otra pero con este problema de fechas en fecha_expiracion que es el que necesito, no he sido capaz de seleccionar unicamente el rango de fechas deseado.

Comment: En MySQL el formato de fechas debe ser YYYY-MM-DD. Si tu recoges las fechas en el formato "humano" dd-mm-yyyy, deberás convertirla antes de hacer la consulta. Yo tenia estos problemas y tuve que hacerme una función fechaMysql() y otra que fuera fechaHumana().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no se puede modificar el tipo de dato de la columna, podrías usar la [función STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Esa función intenta convertir un STRING en un objeto DATE o DATETIME según el formato que se le indique.

Por ejemplo, la consulta que intentabas hacer, podría reescribirse así:

```
SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(fecha_expiracion, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31'
```

Asumo que en tu servidor el formato de fecha es `YYYY-MM-DD` (o, utilizando cadenas de formato de MySQL, 'Y-m-d'), porque en la imagen adjunta a tu pregunta se ve parte de la columna `CREATION_DATE`, utilizando parte de ese formato, por eso reescribí las fechas del `BETWEEN` como *AÑO-MES-DIA*, pero si hubiera alguna configuración extraña en cuanto a fechas, también podrías aplicar `STR_TO_DATE` a esos parámetros:

```
SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(fecha_expiracion, '%d-%m-%Y')
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-05-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31-05-2019', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Pero ten en cuenta que todo ésto es sólo una solución apurada.
Las consultas del estilo de la que te comparto suelen ser mucho más lentas de lo que podrían ser si los tipos de datos fueran los correctos.